# Is there any way I can show $\theta(x)\theta^2(x)=x^{p-1}$, for $\theta\in \operatorname{Aut}(C_p)$ having order $3$

Tags: group-theory

So I am not sure if I am being dim but I am stuck on what seems like a straightforward group theory argument. Suppose we have some $\theta\in \operatorname{Aut}(C_p)\cong C_{p-1}$ such that $\theta^3=1$ (obviously, $3\mid p-1$). If $x\in C_p$ I want to show the following: $\theta(x)\theta^2(x)=x^{p-1}$. As an example, let $p=7$, then we have $\theta(x)=x^2$ being such a $\theta$ where $x^2 x^4=x^6$.

Comment: While in the title you say "order $3$", in the body you only say "$\theta^3=1$". This would allow $\theta=1$, for which both the claim (and the "obviously $3\mid p-1$") are false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let we talk about $\mathbb F_p$ instead of $C_p$. 
Then the group operation in $\mathbb C_p$ is addition and the automorphism  $\theta$ is multiplication by some $a=\theta(1)\in\mathbb F_p$ with $a^3=1$ and $a\ne 1$.
You want to show that $ax+a^2x=-x$ for all $x$. But that follows because $a$ is a root of the polynomial $X^3-1=(X-1)(X^2+X+1)$ and not of $X-1$.

Comment: Thank you, I new I was being silly!